# Red dots in elasticsearch index output

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

What are the red dots that Kibana inserts in index data as seen in this image? This is from me performing a simple query on a description field in my local environment. At first I thought they may be calling out invalid characters, but I don't know why (for example) B or 5 would be invalid. They are not part of the data, i.e. you cannot copy/paste them, which is why I'm led to believe they're some sort of warning. I have tried a variety of Google searches, but haven't come up with anything in the documentation or otherwise.
[image: red dots in ES output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the answer here: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/what-is-this-red-dot-in-index-data/269612/8 - they were non breaking spaces. I replaced them with regular spaces in my string and the red dots went away.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure about that they are not from your data ingestion pipeline or they are not already exit in you input data before indexing, I guess it happens in analyzer level, It happens when you indexing documents with regard of your analyzing strategy (here in your case, I guess it's Elastic default strategy) and creating tokens from input streams to create inverted index tables for different fields.

If you look at it this happened in your text when the Alphabet word followed by numeric annotations, By red dots he tries to show the case of unplanned tokens which he created by his own for inverted index tables.
For more info:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-analyzers.html